# C# 'if' key word inside <script> tag in razor view

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm trying to write the following code inside ASP.Net-MVC razor view but the page won't compile.

```
<script>     

    @(if (Model.IsValid))
     {
        ("#ErrorMessage).text("Error");
     }
    else
    {
       ("#Registration).text("Done!");
    }

</script>
```

There are workarounds that I did to achieve that operation, but is there a simple way?

Comment: Interesting tidbit: the `<script>` breaks this question in the RSS feed.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    @if (ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        <text>$('#ErrorMessage').text('Error');</text>
    }
    else
    {
        <text>$('#Registration').text('Done!');</text>
    }
</script>
```

Things to notice:

- usage of `ViewData.ModelState.IsValid` to test if there are modelstate errors
- usage of the special `<text>` to indicate to the razor parser to use the text as is
- usage of the `$` function as I suppose this is jQuery code
- properly closing quotes around javascript strings
- usage of the `type="text/javascript"` attribute on the script tag.

Comment: You are right about your comments, I just gave a simple example (With stupid errors), checking the <text> now

Comment: As always your answer was helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a workaround that may look a little better:

```
<script>
    var modelIsValid = '@ViewData.ModelState.IsValid' == '@true';
    if(modelIsValid)
    {
        $("#ErrorMessage").text("Error");
    }
    else
    {
        $("#Registration").text("Done!");
    }
</script>
```

Using '@true' makes sure that the true string is always correct (rather than hardcoding it like 'True').